# Datetime / Timestamp is considered as String while reading CSV file in Spark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am reading CSV files in spark and inferring schema

Having difficulties in transforming schema correctly.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true',dateFormat ='yyyy-MM-dd').load('ACTIVITY.csv')

# I have to use below two lines to convert the String type to time stamp
#df = (df.withColumn('START_DT', df.START_DT.cast('timestamp'))
#       .withColumn('END_DT', df.END_DT.cast('timestamp')))
df.printSchema()
```

Is there a better way to infer schema rather than type casting every single column? In my use case it is a possibility I will have huge number of columns and type casting every single column will be difficult.

Comment: one easiest way is to define a schema and use that schema while reading the csv file

Comment: What type do the timestamp columns get when you infer the schema? String? Also, which version of Spark do you use?

Comment: TimeStamp is coming as String , Spark version is 2.3

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan : Problem with creating a schema is it will be a static struct type I have 10 different files in AWS S3 folder I am trying to infer schema . Maintaining multiple schema types will be difficult.